# Crystal Report display only Specific column from datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, crystal-reports

I'm using window form application c#. I would like to display the content in crystal report from datagridview.
I tried using datasource which displays all the content in the datagridview. 
I would limit the column 2 out of 5 column only to be displayed in crystal report.
For example
datagridview consist of ID,Name,Mobile, address, email
crystal report must display Name, Mobile only.

Comment: Have you thought about using a Boolean Parameter for each column and set it to Yes/NO as you require and then use it in the suppression formula of all the fields in one column to show/hide it.

Comment: @aMazing Thank for your support. 
Thing is i have cart datagridview from which i have to filter and export to datagridview

Comment: OK may be your requirement is not coming out clear in your question. If you edit your question and give some more detail more people would be able to understand it and then guide you. @suuz